# anchor won't center vertically inside list item

Tags: css, hyperlink, anchor, center, vertical-alignment

I am trying to center an anchor horizontally AND vertically inside a list.

```
#menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 12px 0 12px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #AAAAAA;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow:
        -2px -2px 0 #000,    
        2px -2px 0 #000,
        -2px 2px 0 #000,
        2px 2px 0 #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9FEDC/2/

All I want is an anchor that:

- is horizontally and vertically centered
- stretches accross the entire parent

EDIT: `text-align` is working fine but not even `vertical-align: middle` is working.

EDIT 2: As suggested, I'm now using a `line-height` equal to the anchor's height. This does indeed get the anchor closer to its vertical center, but for some reason it is still a few pixels off its true vertical center. Here's an updated fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/zp5GM/1/

EDIT 3: just out of curiosity I defined a 1px solid border for the anchor element and saw that the text INSIDE the anchor itself is not centered vertically. So things like `vertical-align` or even position changes to the anchor do not affect *anything* in this regard. 
Can somebody please explain this weird behavior?

Comment: Well for starters, your HTML in invalid. A `<ul>` can only have a `<li>` as a child.

Comment: True ty for pointing that out, fixed. However, this isn't really related to my issue right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been mentioned, your markup is invalid. Once that is fixed, you can center the anchor tag by doing something similar to this:

Set the width and text alignment to the anchor's parent instead of the anchor itself.

```
li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

To vertically align and element, you can take different approaches. The easiest is probably to give the element the same height and line-height. That way it will vertically center the text.

```
<div class="parent-element">
  <div class="child-element">
    <p>This is some text.</p>
  </div>
</div>

.parent-element {
  width: 100%;
}

.child-element {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

You can also position it 50% from the top and then subtract half the height of the child element.

```
<div class="parent-element">
  <div class="child-element">
    <p>This is some text.</p>
  </div>
</div>

.parent-element { position: relative; }
.child-element {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: "text-align" only affects horizontal alignment, right? I'm having trouble with _vertical_ alignment.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize you were trying to vertically align the element. I'll update my answer to explain vertical alignment too.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer - haven't thought of line-height at all. This does make it better, but for some reason it's still like 2px off the vertical center. I'll leave it at this for now, but I really don't understand what is happening here. I've never had this much problems with simply aligning an element properly. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a list here or something....no idea. Thanks for helping though!

Answer (score -1):

```
text-align:center;
```

That should do it.

Comment: I've edited my question to be more clear - I am having trouble centering the link vertically. "vertical-align: middle" doesn't seem to be working either...